# User with favourites and likes system in Mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model, schema

I want to create a DB with Users which also have a reference to another DB called "Library" which has "favourites" and "likes". I will show the idea here:

User Model

```
const userSchema = Schema({
    username: {type: String, minlength: 4, maxlength: 10, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    library: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Library'}
}, { timestamps: true});
```

Library Model

```
    const librarySchema = new Schema({
    likes: [{
        likeId: {type: String},
        mediaType: {type: String}
    }],
    favourites: [{
        favId: {type: String},
        mediaType: {type: String}
    }],
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

Can you please tell me if this is the right way to implement these models or if there is a better way?
At the moment if I try to call

```
User.findOne({email: 'xxx@xxx.com'}).populate('library').exec(function (err, library)
```

it doesn't find anything...

Library POST request

```
router.post('/favourites', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), function (req, res) {
const favouritesFields = {};
if (req.body.favId) favouritesFields.favId = req.body.favId;
if (req.body.mediaType) favouritesFields.mediaType = req.body.mediaType;
Library.findOne({user: req.user._id}).then(library => {
    if (library) {
        Library.update({user: req.user._id}, {$push: {favourites: favouritesFields}})
            .then(library => res.json(library));
    } else {
        new Library({user: req.user._id, favourites: favouritesFields}).save().then(library => res.json(library));
    }
});
});
```

User POST request

```
router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
const {errors, isValid} = validateSignupInput(req.body);

if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
}
// Check if email already exists
User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (user) {
    if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            title: 'Email already exists'
        });
    }
});
// Create and save the new user
let user = new User({
    username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
});
user.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occurred during the signup',
            error: err
        });
    }
    res.status(201).json({
        title: 'User created',
        obj: result
    });
```

Comment: what's the value of "library" within exec's callback ? also, you realise that should be "foundUser" or something, not "library", since what that query should get you is a user with its library attribute populated, not the library itself.

Comment: Hi @rakan316, you're right, but I didn't realised it. By the way the values it returns it's the entire User: 
{ isVerified: true,
  _id: 5b030aeab78fbafb7c75a06e,
  username: 'user',
  email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
  password: '$2a$10$OkhKizZ/3wC1ieBtfXQPNuSHynbT5hPdOY1Yv45xCAjFel9xIz8fC',
  createdAt: 2018-05-21T18:07:42.128Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-05-21T18:07:56.996Z,
  __v: 0 }

without libraries' values

Comment: Edit your post to add the code you use to assign the library attribute to a user and save the changes. That’s where something is going wrong, it’s not that foundUser.library isn’t returned or populated, its that it doesnt exist, that’s why “foundUser.library” would give you undefined

Comment: @rakan316 added Library and User POST requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is **not** with the query you're making. there is no foundUser.library because one was never added.

You're adding users to libraries, but you're not adding libraries to your users. if you run the following code in your app:

```
Library.find({}).populate("user").exec(function(err, foundLibraries){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(foundLibraries);
    }
});
```

You would see that the libraries have their "user" properties, that when populated contain the entire user document as an object. But, the reason that isn't working for foundUser.library when you query for users is that foundUser.library was never assigned. you know how you're assigning the email, username and password when creating users, you have to do the same for the library property. Or, in your case, since a library is only created after the user, you can just set the value of user.library in the callback of creating/saving the library.

Comment: Exactly, thank you. I've just added some code in the creating/saving library callback to actually add to the found user its library. I wrongly thought it was an automatic process, that's why I didn't do that.